# Рандомное число в веденном диапазоне чисел

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно выполнить задание: вывод случайного числа из введенного диапазона, после нажатия на кнопку. Получился такой код, но генерация не работает.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>random</title>
<meta name="charset" content="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

<fieldset id="generation">
<p>От
<input id="num1" type="text"></input>
</p>
<p>До
<input id="num2" type="text"></input>
</p>
<input type="submit" class="button" onclick="getnum()"></input>
<br>
</fieldset> 


<script type="text/javascript">
function getnum() {
    var first = document.getElementsById('num1').value);
    var second = document.getElementsById('num2').value);

    var numout = Math.floor(Math.random()*(second-first+1)+first);
    alert(numout);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В строке `var first = document.getElementsById('num1').value);` и второй не нужны последние скобки.
Так же при получении рандомного числа - переводите значения введённых данных к числам через `+`.

```js
    function getnum() {
        let first = document.getElementById('num1').value;
        let second = document.getElementById('num2').value;

        let numout = Math.floor(Math.random()*(+second-+first)+(+first));
        alert(numout);
    }
```

```html
<fieldset id="generation">
    <p>От
        <input id="num1" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <p>До
        <input id="num2" type="text"></input>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="getnum()">
    <br>
</fieldset>
```